# Is it possible to animate a ViewCell when it appears or disappears?

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin.Forms and recently has an ideal that don't know how to implement it. So saying a ListView has server items and items are decorated within a ViewCell. ViewCell is derived from View which has public event *appearing* and *disappearing*. How can I animate the ViewCell when it appearing or disappering? For example fade in or fade out. Form the [classes hierarchy](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Element/) , `View` is a subclass of `Element` but has no relation with `VisualElement` which support animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always animate the child view: [`ViewCell.View`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ViewCell.View/) when appearing or disappering event occurs.